# Iterating through a list and Dictionary and Turning into DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I'm trying to take specific lists from this data that I scraped to turn it into a Pandas Dataframe but I am getting the following error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Here is the data;

```
r = requests.get(url).json()

print(r)
```

Output:

```
[{'category': {'id': 34,
   'name': 'Tech',
   'shortname': 'tech',
   'sort_name': 'Tech'},
  'city': 'Edinburgh',
  'country': 'GB',
  'created': 1450173286000,
  'description': "<p>We're passionate about security, as are you.</p>\n<p>We want to invite the security community in Scotland to engage 5 or 6 times a year to discuss all things security. A informal forum to share ideas, make contacts, encourage debate.</p>\n<p>Our MeetUps will 100% NOT be sales-led. There will be no vendors, no sponsors, no obligation to talk to anyone, nor cost any money to attend.</p>\n<p>They will be hosted at a number of venues, but there will be no hosting-company focus, we merely organise and host the events, with a choice of speakers as well as the obligatory refreshments!</p>",
  'id': 19213863,
  'join_mode': 'open',
  'key_photo': {'base_url': 'https://secure.meetupstatic.com',
   'highres_link': 'https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/event/d/e/c/4/highres_445137028.jpeg',
   'id': 445137028,
   'photo_link': 'https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/event/d/e/c/4/600_445137028.jpeg',
   'thumb_link': 'https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/event/d/e/c/4/thumb_445137028.jpeg',
   'type': 'event'},
  'lat': 55.94,
  'link': 'https://www.meetup.com/Security-MeetUp-Scotland/',
  'localized_country_name': 'United Kingdom',
  'localized_location': 'Edinburgh, United Kingdom',
  'lon': -3.2,
  'members': 1059,
  'meta_category': {'category_ids': [34],
   'id': 292,
   'name': 'Tech',
   'photo': {'base_url': 'https://secure.meetupstatic.com',
    'highres_link': 'https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/event/2/e/a/d/highres_450131949.jpeg',
    'id': 450131949,
    'photo_link': 'https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/event/2/e/a/d/600_450131949.jpeg',
    'thumb_link': 'https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/event/2/e/a/d/thumb_450131949.jpeg',
    'type': 'event'},
   'shortname': 'tech',
   'sort_name': 'Tech'},
  'name': 'Security MeetUp Scotland',
  'next_event': {'id': '245752465',
   'name': 'Security Scotland Chapter 10 - hosted by Skyscanner!',
   'time': 1516820400000,
   'utc_offset': 0,
   'yes_rsvp_count': 130},
  'organizer': {'bio': 'I do Security stuff. Currently at Capital One.\nOrganiser of Security Scotland: https://www.meetup.com/Security-MeetUp-Scotland\nHusband, proud daddy, guitarist, drummer, muso, ex-DJ/producer, Fleetwood Mac aficionado, Scottish Leeds fan.',
   'id': 192768669,
   'name': 'Stu Hirst',
   'photo': {'base_url': 'https://secure.meetupstatic.com',
    'highres_link': 'https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/member/8/d/9/7/highres_250956247.jpeg',
    'id': 250956247,
    'photo_link': 'https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/member/8/d/9/7/member_250956247.jpeg',
    'thumb_link': 'https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/member/8/d/9/7/thumb_250956247.jpeg',
    'type': 'member'}},
  'score': 1.0,
  'state': 'U8',
  'status': 'active',
  'timezone': 'Europe/London',
  'urlname': 'Security-MeetUp-Scotland',
  'visibility': 'public',
  'who': 'Scot Security Folks'},
{'category': {'id': 34, ...
 ]
```

I understand that this has many dictionaries and I want to get the main ones. I have tried to that like so;

```
for item in r['category']:
    print (item['name'])
    print (item['city'])
    print (item['members'])

for item in r['meta_category']:
print (item['name'])
print (item['country'])
print (item['status'])
```

And more, but then that is when I receive the error. Can you help to allow me to create a DataFrame with `'name', 'city, 'country', 'lat', 'lon', 'description', 'members', 'status', 'url-name'` from `'category'` and `'meta_category'`

Comment: Is the data from https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?zip=eh1+1af&offset=0&city=Edinburgh&format=json&lon=-3.19000005722&category_id=34&photo-host=public&page=500&radius=25.0&fields=&lat=55.9500007629&order=id&desc=false&sig_id=243750775&sig=9072b77fb34f5b84a392da2505fd946c58e94fe5?

Comment: Also, another thing. You haven't examined or understood the structure of the response probably. From your code, this will never work. Take a look at `r['results']` and see what you get.

Comment: yes that's the one

Comment: Also, I see `results`. Inside `results` is a list of dicts. Inside each dict, I only see `category`.

Comment: hmmm... with `r['results']` I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: We must be calling different URLs then, since it seems our structures are slightly different. Mind showing what `url` holds?

Comment: I am using both urls. So I was trying to create two DFs to analyse for which is better data . The groups one u mentioned and my the second one which is a  find groups:  "https://api.meetup.com/find/groups?upcoming_events=false&photo-host=public&location=Edinburgh&country=United+Kingdom&sig_id=243750775&radius=smart&category=34&sig=a4ffcecc266f48634007b590dbd0c270f29e26f1"

Comment: I see. This url gives me an "Invalid Signature" on response. I cannot give you code (since I don't have data) but I have an idea. You'll need to keep a list of columns you want. Iterate over each dict in the result extracting values for each key. Put each value into a new dict of lists. Pass that to a dataframe.

Comment: no problem. with the groups url you called. The issue i have with that one is the topics columns ... I need to split that and i've tried iterating over it but to no avail. `df.topics` gives me `[{'id': 417, 'name': 'Web Standards', 'urlkey': 'webstandards'},
 {'id': 659, 'name': 'Web Design', 'urlkey': 'webdesign'},
 {'id': 10209, 'name': 'Web Technology', 'urlkey': 'web'},
 {'id': 28990, 'name': 'CMS (Content Management Systems)', 'urlkey': 'cms'}]` and I want the 'name' for each seperated by comma... can u help?

Comment: Try this? `df.topics.apply(lambda x: [y['name'] for y in x if 'name' in y])`

Comment: Also with the 'find/groups' url you say keep a list of columns and iterate over the dict but isn't that what I have been trying to do with the `for item in ['category'] ` loop above ?

Comment: Something like this: `cols = ['name', 'city', 'country', 'lat', 'lon', 'description', 'members', 'status', 'url-name']` ... `d = defaultdict(list); for rr in r: for c in cols:  d[c].append(rr[c])`

Comment: Modify that is needed so it accesses the right keys. I can't confirm the correctness since I don't have all your data.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you so much! Always clearing things up and teaching me some new stuff. You are Amazing :)

Comment: Oh, it worked? Cool! You're welcome :-)

Comment: Well, the one for /groups worked and now I can analyse according to topics but still working on the other one (no giving up!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so json, as you already know consists of a list of dictionaries and as such, there can also be "sub-dictionaries". In your case, you have a big dictionary with a lot of keys and also some smaller ones, for example, the **'category'** :

category has 4 keys *(id, name, shortname, sort_name)*

when you tried to loop through the r['category'] you caught an error because the keys you wanted to find in the category dictionary are not in there! but in the big one (which in my case is called data)

so the following works as one would expect:

```
import json

data = json.load(open('test.json'))
columns = ['city', 'country', 'lat', 'lon',
           'description', 'members', 'status', 'urlname']

for meetup in data:
    print(meetup['category']['name'])
    for item in columns:
        print(meetup[item])
```

now you only have to figure out how you want to transfer the data into the df, this can be done for example by csv. If this is unclear I can also help you

Comment: Is 'test.json' the same as `url.json()' in this case because I'm getting an error

Comment: data should equal your json object (i think its 'r' in your case)

Comment: Yep data is 'r' in this case. Even after trying that I'm still receiving this error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` I think the issue lies in the API url call

Comment: edit: since you have a list of dict-objects you also need to loop through those